# Am I going to be installing this motion-sensor light switch correctly in a 2-gang box?

Tags: switch, smart-switch

I'm currently planning on installing a motion-sensing switch for the lights in the bathroom.

The current light switch shares a box with the switch for the ventilator fan (which I don't plan on replacing for now).

The current setup is:

1. The load wires (item A and item B in the photo) for the lights and fan respectively are connected to each switch
2. The line wires (item C and item D in the photo) are connected to each switch as well on the second screw
3. For some reason, there is an additional wire (item E) daisy chaining the line wires of the two switches (connecting where item C and D connect to their respective switches).

[image: Current State]

I want to replace the switch on the left in the photo above with a new motion-sensing switch (see photo below).

Would it be correct for me to do the following:

1. Pigtail one of the black wires on my new switch to the load wire (pigtailing B1 in the photo below with A in the photo above)
2. Pigtail the other black wire on my new switch to the line wire **AND THE WIRE CONNECTING THE TWO SWITCHES** (pigtailing B2 in the photo below with C **AND E** in the photo above)
3. Pigtail the neutral wire to the bundle of white neutral wires that are already in the box;
4. Connect the ground wire so that it is touching the metal box (screwing in G in the photo below to the metal box)

[image: New switch]

I wanted to run it by y'all before potentially setting my house on fire and killing myself and my family.

Thanks!

Comment: Since you are concerned about fire I would suggest checking the UL listing or lack of there are many products available online that do not meet code compliance and by the colors of the wires I would guess this is an inferior import product that may be a fire hazard in itself.

Comment: What make and model is the new motion sensor?

Answer (score 1):

C and D are not both supply hots. One of them is supplying hot to both switches. The other is carrying hot on to another load somewhere, maybe an outlet in the bathroom. The jumper across the switches is carrying hot from the source to the other switch and to the further load.

Your plan for the new switch sounds correct to me.

Comment: Hmmm - that make sense! If that’s the case, do you know if there would be any issues if the new switch is a 2A switch, if the overall daisy chain circuit is 15A?

Comment: @leer317        If the switch is really rated for 2 Amp, that's 240 Watts maximum for the lights.  Does that green sleeve slide off that wire by any chance?  If it's a neutral, it shouldn't be green.

Comment: @JACK yeah - the instructions tell me to take off the green sleeve covering the white wire when connecting the neutral wires.